# How to calcul a sum of string list in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I use texfield to add number. After this I save in sharepreference  the value in List

I search to make an addition of each value saved in this List

I tried this, but it doesn't works.

```
  load_list()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {

      stringList = prefs.getStringList("list");


     sum = stringList.reduce((value, element) => value + element);

    });

  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[reduce](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html) returns the same type as the type in the collection, so you should use [fold](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.1/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html) instead.

```dart
final List<String> stringList = prefs.getStringList("list") ?? [];
final int sum = stringList.fold<int>(0, (prev, value) => prev + int.parse(value));
```

To make it completely null-safe:

```dart
final int sum = stringList.fold<int>(0, (prev, value) => prev + (int.tryParse(value ?? '0') ?? 0));
```

Comment: Just for safety I would do ```int.tryParse(value) ?? 0```

Comment: There's no need for ```value ?? '0'``` inside the ```tryParse```

Comment: @danypata if you're sure in your data, yes. But if you pass null to `int.tryParse` it will throw an exception, be careful.